# Is there a way in C++ to use string with switch Statement?

Tags: c++

Currently I am trying to get user input by using **string** with **switch**, but the compiler is angry and it gives an exception and it closes with an unknown error.
This is my code that I am trying.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string day;
   cout << "Enter The Number of the Day between 1 to 7 ";
   cin >> day;
  switch (day) {
  case 1:
    cout << "Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    cout << "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    cout << "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    cout << "Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    cout << "Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    cout << "Saturday";
    break;
  case 7:
    cout << "Sunday";
    break;
default:
    cout << "Attention, you have not chosen the Valid number to Identify weekly days from 1 to 7. Try again!" << endl;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `string day` with `int day`, or before you go into the `switch`, convert `day` from a `string` to an `int` such as with `std::stoi()`.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to use a string in a switch statement, in this simple example you can replace `string day;` with `int day;`. If the variable must be a string you can always convert it to an int, there are several tools you can use to do so, `strtol` and `stoi` to name a couple.